# magento change the completed order status into custom order status

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

I have a order with the '**complete**' status. I need to change it to a custom status.

I tried below code;

```
$orderId = '1000000055';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId, 'increment_id');
$order->setState('custom_status_code', true);
$order->save();
```

But that not working. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion  create ***a status*** of ***state complete*** then assign than custom status.

> ```
> $orderId = '1000000055';
> $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
> $order->setStatus('custom_status_code');
> $order->save();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

custom order statuses can be configured via the backend. Navigate to System -> Order Statuses and here you can create your custom order status there.
Then you can save order using @Amit Bera's code.

you can also get help from here:- http://codelea.com/9xzA1xWDKgpQ/change-order-status-in-magento-via-sql.html

 or 
http://www.techytalk.info/programmatically-add-new-order-state-and-status-in-magento/